# Hay alguna forma de pasar un arreglo a una función o metodo del controlador que no sea por la URL en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ajax

Hola a todos mi problema es el siguiente 
Necesito pasar un arreglo de muchos usuarios de una vista a una función o metodo del controlador , en dicha función debo generar un pdf  con los datos del arreglo, inicialmente pasaba el arreglo por la URL,  pero el arreglo tiene demasiados usuarios es muy grande y me genera un not found 
Alguien sabe de  alguna otra manera de  enviar el arreglo al controlador?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español. Sí, como [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData),  [conviertiendo el objeto o valor de JavaScript en una cadena de texto JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify). Prueba algo y si te encuentras con algún obstáculo,[edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/315452/edit) la pregunta agregando un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que llevas hecho.

Comment: También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla, y lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Mirate el método stringify de javascript, convierte un objeto o valor de JavaScript en una cadena de texto                        https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

Agradezco su colaboración prestada
ya me envía los datos del arreglo al controlador, pero el problema que ahora tengo es que no me descarga el archivo, asumo que es por el método que se esta usando que es de tipo POST.
Dejo lo que llevo de código y a ver si me pueden seguir colaborando 
Esta es la función que hago en la vista para enviar el array al controlador

```
 function genera() {
                    var array=JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($resultado) ?>);
                    var  formdata = new FormData();
                    formdata.append("array",array)

                    $.ajax({
                        url:"{{route('exceltarjetasactivadas')}}",
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType:"html",
                        data: formdata,
                        cache:false,
                        contentType:false,
                        processData:false,

                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                    });
                    }
```

Esta es la ruta

```
Route::post('reportes/tarjetasactivadas/exportarexcel','ReportesController@excelTarjetasActivadas')->name('exceltarjetasactivadas');
```

y este es el controlador

```
function excelTarjetasActivadas(Request $request)
{
    $resultado = $request->all();
    $totalrow = sizeof($resultado) + 5;
    return \Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::download(new TarjetasActivadasExports($totalrow, $resultado, sizeof($resultado)), 'Tarjetas Activadas.xls');
}
```

Agradezco sus respuestas y ojala me puedan seguir orientando con lo que me hace falta Gracias